# Push notification in S40 and S60

Tags: s60, series-40, nokia-s40

I want to implement an app that makes use of push notifications. Any ideas about how to start and links to resources will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I think this http://projects.developer.nokia.com/notificationsapi/wiki is a very good starting place for push notifications. I hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

[Nokia Developer have](http://library.developer.nokia.com/topic/Java_Developers_Library/GUID-A317C9AE-ABD0-4887-B2C0-77A2FB5A66E2.html) a good starting place with links to more resources